# Error: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=READ_EXECUTE,

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I'm using hadoop-1.2.1 version on CentOS6 machine, and have configured, its running successfully, also I have installed plug-in of hadoop in Eclipse kepler, but unfortunately I got an Error of permission denied which I have showed in the picture, I tried to resolve this by reading many blogs but still I'm stuck there.. 
can someone solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: `user=root`? Fix _that_ first. You should not run anything as root unless absolutely required and in Java it is required 0% of the time or close to.

Comment: how can I fix user=root?

Comment: By running hadoop with a non root user

Comment: I simply started hadoop with bin/start-all.sh, sorry I'm not getting you by saying running hadoop with a non root user, can you define which command should I run for this issue please?

Answer (score 1):

I have understand from your question and I suppose that you are logging in with 'root' of your Operating System to start Hadoop.

I suggest restart your system and login from the 'Hadoop' (that is given with the Users list, e.g. root, Guest, Hadoop), then start the Hadoop.. It will work then..